In Power Automate Get just email address values from Select
I'm trying to get a semicolon separated list of email addresses stored in a SharePoint list's text field.
My workflow gets items from SharePoint, uses a 'Select' action to just get the email address field, Compose action to 'chunk' the responses into smaller arrays, & join the values together with a semicolon. However, when I do this, it includes the header ("Email") in each one.

What I've tried
In the Compose

chunk(body('Select')['Email'],20)

Error: The template language expression 'chunk(body('Select')['Email'],20)' cannot be evaluated because property 'Email]' cannot be selected. Array elements can only be selected using an integer index.
In the email:

join(item()['Email'],';')

Error: The template language expression 'join(item()['Email'],';')' cannot be evaluated because property 'Email' cannot be selected. Array elements can only be selected using an integer index.

join(item()[0]['Email'],';')

Error: The template language function 'join' expects its first parameter to be an array. The provided value is of type 'String


I figure it out.  I just had to change the "Select" to text mode from "Key Value Mode" and specify the SharePoint field.  This removed the column header and just gave me the values.

